# order of $\mathbb{Z}^\times_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra

what is the order of $\mathbb{Z}^\times_m$?  I'm not sure how to approach the problem.  I'm pretty sure the answer depends on whether m is prime or not but past that I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2):

The order is given by the number of positive integers (less than $m$) relatively prime to $m$. We denote this as $\varphi(m)$, the Euler Totient function.

So, for example, if $m = 12$, the numbers 1,5,7,11 are relatively prime to $m$, so $\mathbb{Z}_{12}^{\times}$ has order 4.

If $m = 17$, all positive integers less than 17 are relatively prime to $m$, so $\mathbb{Z}_{17}^{\times}$ has order 16.

Comment: What definition of order do you use?

Comment: What other type of order of a group are you thinking of? When speaking of a group, order means "number of elements."

Answer (score 0):

To find the classes modulo $m$ that has inverse, you just got to see which of the residues $0,1,2,...m-1$ are relative prime versus $m$.

The classes $\bar{a}$ with the greatest common divisor $(a,m)=1$ will have inverse.